# Creating Leads in Marketo using REST API

Tags: ajax, rest, marketo

I am trying to create leads in Marketo using their `/rest/v1/leads.json` endpoint. The process is working, but will not save 2 custom values for the lead - but the Name, email, phone etc are all getting saved for the new lead. The form is not a Marketo generated form, and I ran across this...

*"The Munchkin admin page also allows you to enable the Munchkin API. With the Munchkin API, you can integrate third party software with Marketo and your web site; do custom tracking of events such as multimedia playback; and use your own, non-Marketo-generated forms to cookie users and/or create new leads in the Marketo database."*

If I am using a non-Marketo-generated form - do I have to use the Munchkin API? I also noticed that there wasn't much in the 'field mapping' area of the admin for these custom fields - but I'm not sure if that matters when creating the lead or not thru the API.

Here is what the call looks like:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'https://xxx-xxx-xxxx.mktorest.com/rest/v1/leads.json?    access_token=tokenhere',
    data: '{    "action":"createOnly","lookupField":"email","partitionName":"name","input":[     {"firstName":'+$( "#first_name" ).val()+',"lastName":'+$( "#last_name"     ).val()+',"Email":'+$( "#email" ).val()+',"Phone":'+$( "#phone"    ).val()+',"Company":'+$( "#company" ).val()+',"Country":'+$( "#00NC00000050DlB"   ).val()+',"Industry":'+$( "#industry"        ).val()+',"googleclickid":'+gclid+',"googleVisitorID":'+accountId+'}]}',
    dataType : 'jsonp',
    crossDomain:true,
    success: function(data) { 
    },
    contentType: "application/json",
    dataType: 'json'
});
```

(`gclid` & `accountId` have a values)

The fieldname `XLS` looks like this:

```
googleclickid    googleclickid    Google click id

googleVisitorID  googleVisitorID  Google Visitor ID
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be able to create Leads including all custom fields using the REST API. No need to use the Munchkin API. Make sure you include the correct field names: in Admin > Field Management you can download an XLS with the field names for the REST API. There are also some system fields that cannot be modified using the REST API.

EDIT:
Based on the additional info you provided, fix the following:

- The field names should all start with a lower case character, see XLS
- remove lookupField and partitionName

To test, I would recommend using an interactive tool like cURL or Postman before updating your script. That allows you to see any error messages and adjust your code accordingly.

(If this solves your issue, please plus the answer; I'm trying to get to 50 reputation so I can comment :-)

Comment: Jep, thanks for answering. Here are the two lines from the fieldnames XLS: googleclickid    googleclickid    Google click id
googleVisitorID  googleVisitorID  Google Visitor ID

Comment: Thanks Jep, I will update the fields names, I didn't catch that. And remove what you suggested.

Comment: Jep, I removed lookupField and partitionName as well as changed the field names to lowercase. Still the values are not showing up. I was trying to see the return object since the error: callback gets hit, but evidently there is an error and the return cuts off:  Object { readyState=4,  status=200,  statusText="success",  more...  but when you click it, there is no helpful data showing...

Comment: Even if there is an error, you'll get HTTP status 200. The error description is in the JSON that is returned. Easiest to see this is via cURL or Postman: have you tried that?

Comment: Hi Jep, I have finally figured out a bunch with this, but still I have yet to get the API call to work. I'm using cURL (php) to make the call and am getting an error : "code":"609","message":"Invalid JSON. Unexpected character ('}' (code 125))

Comment: I've looked at the data string, and it looks right. I can't figure out why the json is invalid. (see above)

Comment: As I was pasting it in above, I tried removing a space and it started working. Thanks again for your help and comments.

Comment: I used this JSON and it works fine:
`{
    "action": "createOnly",
    "input": [
        {
            "firstName": "first_name",
            "lastName": "last_name",
            "Email": "email@email.com",
            "Phone": "phone",
            "Company": "company",
            "Country": "00NC00000050DlB",
            "Industry": "industry"
        }
    ]
}`

Comment: Thanks again Jep, it's all working now. I really appreciate you taking the time to answer.